# Finding Linear Transformations such that $TS$ is Injective and Surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Give an example of linear transformations and vector spaces $S\colon U\to V$ and $T\colon V\to W$ such that $TS$ is injective and surjective, but neither S nor T is both injective and surjective.

I need help coming up with a specific example that meets the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

$$U=W=\mathbb{R}^1 , V=\mathbb{R}^2$$
$$S(x) =(x,0) , T(x,y)=x $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are allowed to have $S$ injective and $T$ surjective. Also note that this means that $U$ and $W$ are isomorphic, and that they are "probably not" isomorphic to $V$ (at least in the case where all of them have a finite dimension).

Take $U$ to be the simplest vector space, and try to think about what could $S$ and $T$ be.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=V=W=\{(x_n):x_n \in \ \mathbb R\}$, $S(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$ and $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_2,x_3,...)$.

Then $TS=id_V$.

Comment: Why the downvote ????? In my example: $TS$ is bijective, $S$ is not surjective and $T$ is not injective. So: why the downvote ?